# LESS mixins only working when declared in the same style sheet

Tags: css, less, mixins

I'm a little confused about something:

I decided to make a global LESS document where I declare my mixins. When the mixins are referenced in other style sheets, they do not work. They only seem to work when they are declared and referenced in the same style sheet. This is really annoying. Is this how LESS is suppose to work?

Thanks!

Bastain

Answer (score 4):

LESS uses an import style that is similar to that used by C and C++. You need to import your mixin stylesheet into your LESS file using the `@import` command before you can use those mixins.

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. Unfortunately I'm getting a message saying "Access to restricted URI denied". Do you happen to know a workaround for this?